# Customize html tag u, set it wider than text

Tags: html, css

Trying to set wider the underline tag  in text. Is it possible to widen the underline using the css? I tried to use the css width but nothings happen.

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/OvAdAqAm/1/edit?html,output)

```
<u>Paragraph</u>
```

```css
u {
    width: 40px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `<span>` instead of `<u>`.  Add a border-bottom and some padding right and that'll be that.

HTML

```
<span>Some text</span>
```

CSS

```
span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ApuJofIb/1/edit)**

Comment: yeah sir! it works. but what if its inside the table. Can you check the link above in my post. thanks.

Comment: I'm just wondering why some people give a down vote for my post, without giving a feedback.